# How do I get data from my Hardware to server or so?

Tags: electrical-engineering, telecommunication

**Brief** I am actually of 17 not even in college but I have dream for making my project/dream/aspiration/or So to come true so I am thinking of making a device that performs a function say like Thermometer measures Temperature, now working and doing the function is not a concern of now (a Question for me), the thing is if I got the data of Reading of final Temp (assume it has performed its temperature calculation and given output [Yep its digital]) so now it gave me some value x .

---

**Problem** I want to get this value x into my server or website (maybe I am unable to express it but I want to get it to me through Internet) and store that value for data of  **Person P** so , I am not sure how I would achieve that. Assume all calculation and functions are done and are independent of device now I just need to know how to store that value for use?  Would it require something like connecting it to a wifi card or similar and making an OS (Till now this has came across my mind )

Comment: Give us some detail on what you using to collect the data such as temperature. This will help provide you with a good solution

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena Actually Its still a thought as I currently in school(last year ) so cant really work on it I am just collecting various methods to work on it after being 18yo . Just wanted to know if it is possible at minimum costing approach .

Comment: Actually its more like for  electrical Reading assume it as power maybe for monitoring the usage of my  main component ( subtly Independent of it )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve your goal. Assume your goal is to publish a temperate data to a server or website. You will need at minimum microcontroller, temperature sensor and wireless module.

One good place to start is [Arduino community](https://www.arduino.cc/). You could purchase a Arduino kit with a temperature sensor and ESP8266 wifi module. There are sufficient resources online to publish data to server or website. Another good place to start is [Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/).

I also suggest you take a look at  [Adafruit.io Internet of Things ESP8266 Wifi starter kit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2680). They use [adafruit.io](https://io.adafruit.com/) IOT cloud to publish data.

**Note:** I have not use these resources in a longtime. Therefore I am not update on the latest trends.

There are other alternate resources online. Let us know how this works out for you. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer apart from that Sorry to go against Site policy to ask what do you think would be the branch of Engineering for studying about making use of these things so that I can create something like as described ? Or is it required to study about them or without it can be done ?

Comment: Most electrical, software, computer science, and computer engineering program will expose you to these topics, generally don't go in depth. Their is abundant of online resources, and Q&A forums like this that can help you.

Comment: So no need of specific degree learning on that?

Comment: Correct, there is plenty of online resource and Q&A forum like engineering stackexchange where you can find good responses. Just need to become active in the forums by asking good questions and responding to questions.

Comment: Anyway what this is called I mean  what to look for sensor specific or building devices or what topic its known by

Comment: I don't understand your previous comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73422/discussion-between-treav-and-mahendra-gunawardena).

Answer (score 0):

Just as Mahendra says, in terms of hardware you'll need your sensors connected to something such as an arduino or raspberry pi and have an internet connection. If using a pi you have both wired/wireless options ready out of the box.

Are you planning on hosting your own server or buying server space? Either way linux would be an easy way to go. Watch [this video](https://youtu.be/vzojwG7OB7c) to set up your own server, it shows you how to install Apache, PHP and MySQL. If buying some webspace, you'll need to buy a domain name from a registrar such as GoDaddy  or 123reg and then buy the space from somewhere such as hostinguk.net, anyone that hosts linux with PHP and sql. Once you've done both, link your domain with the webspace.

Now you have everything, you can program your hardware to read the sensor input and send it to your websites database. There are countless guides on all of this online, this answer should point you in the right direction atleast.

Comment: For the time being was thinking about just thinking about data and its transfer not on that but thanks @CraigC